# Is input validation a reasonable usecase for multimethods in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, multimethod

In the [clojure.org documentation on multimethods](http://clojure.org/reference/multimethods) it states:

`Clojure multimethods ... can do validation of arguments and route to error-handling methods etc.`

However, I don't see many examples of anyone using multimethods for this purpose. In the situation where I need to implement only a single method definition, does it still make sense to use multimethods to do input validation? For example:

```
(defmulti divide
          (fn [a b] (if (zero? b)
                      (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "Cannot divide by zero"))
                      :ok)))
(defmethod divide :ok [a b] (quot a b))
```

The advantage of this is that it keeps the final implementation of `divide` clean of input checking or error handling. Is there are more idiomatic way to get validation, error handling and clean syntax?

Answer (score 5):

This is not what is meant by "route to error-handling methods". The technique being suggested is more like this:

```
(defmulti divide (fn [num denom] denom))
(defmethod divide 0 [num denon]
  (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "Cannot divide by zero")))
(defmethod divide :default [a b] (quot a b))
```

The error doesn't come from the dispatch function itself: rather, the dispatch function finds erroneous input values, and sends them to a dedicated error-handler, so that the other methods know they will always get valid input.

Comment: Thanks, would this still be a valid use of multimtehods though? Or would a simple if at the start of the function be more idiomatic?